# Repeated running count of column based on date - Tableau

Tags: count, row, tableau-api

Hi I want to know the index of the purchase
number of a client based on the purchasing date.

[Starting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQBth.jpg)

So I want to count the purchases made by each
person and numbering them by date. The new
row will be:

[Final table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iN1K.jpg)

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way is to create a Calculated Field called "One" with the value of 1.  Then put it on the Text Mark Card, add a Table Calculation.  Specify "specific dimensions" so you can choose the value of "Client" in the 'restarting every' column.  See the picture below.

Table calcs are dependent on the order of the data.  If you want the numbering to be completely independent of the visual representation than you would be best served by using Tableau Prep which can add the field to your data source.

[image: Tableau table calculation]